# tf.keras.utils.to_categorical mixing classes

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras

I am using `tf.keras.utils.to_categorical()` for data preparation.
I have this very simple list and I want to get the categorical values out of it.
So I do this:

```
tf.keras.utils.to_categorical([1,2,3], num_classes=6)
```

and I get:

```
array([[0., 1., 0., 0., 0., 0.],
   [0., 0., 1., 0., 0., 0.],
   [0., 0., 0., 1., 0., 0.]], dtype=float32)
```

Now for further usage, I reduce the values I sent to the function by 1, to get a amount of 6 classes, without 0 as placeholder:

```
tf.keras.utils.to_categorical([x -1 for x in [1,2,3]], num_classes=6)
```

which results in this:

```
array([[1., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0.],
       [0., 1., 0., 0., 0., 0.],
       [0., 0., 1., 0., 0., 0.]], dtype=float32)
```

Now comes the weird part. I want to set certain features to 0 and thats why I found this behaviour:

```
tf.keras.utils.to_categorical([x -1 for x in [-4,2,3]], num_classes=6)
```

results in:

```
array([[0., 1., 0., 0., 0., 0.],
       [0., 1., 0., 0., 0., 0.],
       [0., 0., 1., 0., 0., 0.]], dtype=float32)
```

So `to_categorical()` is mixing -4 and 2 into the same class, which I find pretty weird. I would have expected an exception as the list was not map-able to 6 classes. But I did not expect this to happen. Is this a bug or a feature, why is this happening?

Thanks!

Comment: Your list will become [-5, 1, 2], if you consider python's indexing with negative indices, this is normal. Also, what do you mean by set certain features to 0?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That's completely normal. It just works consistently with Python's negative indexing. See:

```
import tensorflow as tf

tf.keras.utils.to_categorical([0, 1, 2, -1, -2, -3])
```

```
array([[1., 0., 0.],
       [0., 1., 0.],
       [0., 0., 1.],
       [0., 0., 1.],
       [0., 1., 0.],
       [1., 0., 0.]], dtype=float32)
```

To put it differently:

```
import tensorflow as tf

a = tf.keras.utils.to_categorical([0, 1, 2],    num_classes=3)
b = tf.keras.utils.to_categorical([-3, -2, -1], num_classes=3)

print(a)
print(b)
```

```
[[1. 0. 0.]
 [0. 1. 0.]
 [0. 0. 1.]]

[[1. 0. 0.]
 [0. 1. 0.]
 [0. 0. 1.]]
```

Comment: I didnt know about negative indexing, now it makes sense. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

If you want to know why this happened, I think to_categorical in keras doesn't work with negative numbers. but if you want to solve it I suggest to make all numbers greater than 0.
this code do that:

```
arr=numpy.array([-5,-4,-2,-1,0,1,2,3,4]) #anything
arr+=(0-arr.min())
```

Answer (score -1):

Keras to_categorical doesn't work for negative numbers. It's clearly written that the numbers must start from 0.

https://keras.io/api/utils/python_utils/#to_categorical-function

If you still need to make it work, make a dictionary to map the negative numbers.